# SQL Server - Order by part of a result

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could lend me a hand.

I have quite a lengthy SQL query.

What i want to do is break down the a column which stores the date and order the results just by the year. part of the query is as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry), 10) 
       as DailyDate 
FROM table 
ORDER BY DailyDate
```

This gives me a 'DailyDate' outputted in the following format:

```
12-07-14
```

The year is the last 2 digits.

Is there a way i can sort results based on those 2 digits?

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(minute, -601, DailyDate ), 10) as DailyDate  FROM
table  
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(minute, -601, DailyDate ), 10), 7, 2), 
         SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(minute, -601, DailyDate ), 10), 4, 2)
```

Comment: This seems to work, is there any way i could sort by the second set of numbers after sorting the year ... so adding a secondary order by?

Comment: we should make use of inbuilt date functions here.. converting a `date` to a `char` and then substring to get something that's a `char` not `datepart` which actually should be the case..here `YEAR` is required not `string`.

Comment: @Kumar: Sorry about this, but if some results are formatted 12-7-14 and some 12-07-14 ... That query will break down wont it?

Answer (score 1):

```
... ORDER BY SUBSTRING(DailyDate, 7, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
ORDER BY right(DailyDate,2)
```

You will be ordering the data only by the last two numbers from right side (In your case thats the year)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry), 10) as DailyDate FROM table ORDER BY ( YEAR( DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry)) % 100 ) ASC,( DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry) ASC
```

the code below is not mandatory Its not mandatory

> ( DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry) ASC

The code you need is

> ( YEAR( DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry)) % 100 ) ASC

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [YEAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186313.aspx) function as:

```
ORDER BY YEAR(DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry))
```

This way your data will be ordered in correct manner when data for years 1900 and 2000 are persent. ( I mean all such cases where last 2 digits are equal).

[Edit] 
To further order by [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187813.aspx) use inbuilt date functions, **don't rely on converted string to order the data**

```
ORDER BY YEAR(DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry)) ,
         MONTH (DateAdd(minute, -601, pay.Expiry))
```